# Oracle Change Management and Configuration Management Pack

Tags: oracle

Is there a query I can run on Oracle to find out if Oracle Change Management or Configuration Management Pack is Installed? I need to run this in our Monitoring Tool for Database Licensing to see if it's installed or not.

I have been looking at other Forums and I haven't come across any information.

PS: I am not a DBA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "packs" are specifically for Oracle Enterprise Manager. If you aren't running OEM anywhere, then you won't have them installed; if you are, you can verify their enablement through the OEM console.

In general you can monitor the usage of any database-level feature (not OEM feature) through the DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS view. Keep in mind that many separately licensed features cannot be uninstalled. Some can be disabled through other means as I describe in the "Dealing with Unlicensed Features" section of this blog post: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/02/11/understanding-the-af-oracle-esla/. With others, you are on the honor system and must use that view to self-monitor.

Comment: Hi, I did not find this information in the DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS. Is there a query we can run?

Comment: The packs you mentioned are not database-level features. They are specific to Oracle Enterprise Manager application. They won't ever show up in database metadata, only in OEM application tables or as viewed through the OEM console. Even then, I believe they are either "enabled" or "disabled"; you can't uninstall them. That on/off switch is handled through the OEM console.

Comment: Is that true for Oracle Advanced Security as well? There is no query to find out if it's Installed/Enabled or not?

Comment: Look for "Transparent Data Encryption" in the DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS view. In many cases you'll need to look for individual features of major options, not the top-level option.

Comment: ASO is a case of an option that is always on because it is required by some internal Oracle functionality - you just have to self-police and not use it independently.